# preparing sql dynamically in oracle stored procedure

Tags: sql, plsql

I have 3 input parameters,based on values of each input parameter i have to prepare the SQL in procedure dynamically. I am doing below way but it is failing, if the parameter value is null,then i have to exclude that from the where clause.

**IN Parameters:**

> empid in varchar2 || empname IN varchar2 || empsal IN varchar2

```
SELECT
      EMP_NAME
INTO
      V_EMP_NAME
FROM
      EMPLOYEE
WHERE
         ( EMP_ID = EMPID
          OR ( EMP_ID IS NULL
             AND EMPID IS NULL ) )
      AND ( EMP_NAME = EMPNAME
          OR ( EMP_NAME IS NULL
             AND EMPNAME IS NULL ) )
      AND ( EMP_SAL = EMPSAL
          OR ( EMP_SAL IS NULL
             AND EMPSAL IS NULL ) );
```

After updates i modified the query like below,it is compiled but giving run time errors saying that ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended on just before EXECUTE IMMEDIATE

```
  V_SQL :='SELECT EMP_NAME INTO V_empname FROM employee WHERE ';
    BEGIN
    IF(EMPID IS NOT NULL) THEN
     V_SQL := V_SQL || ' emp_id='||EMPID;
    END IF; 
    IF(EMPNAME IS NOT NULL) THEN
      V_SQL := V_SQL || ' AND emp_name='||EMPNAME;
    END IF; 
    IF(V_empsalIS NOT NULL) THEN
      V_SQL := V_SQL || ' AND  emp_sal='||empsal;
 V_SQL := V_SQL ||' AND ACTIVE =''Y''' ;
    END IF; 
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_SQL;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      V_check:= '' ;
    END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are another alternative:

```
V_SQL_WHERE := null;

  V_SQL :='SELECT EMP_NAME INTO V_empname FROM employee';
    BEGIN

    IF(EMPID IS NOT NULL) THEN
      V_SQL_WHERE := V_SQL_WHERE || ' emp_id='||EMPID;
    END IF; 

    IF(EMPNAME IS NOT NULL) THEN

      IF (V_SQL_WHERE is not null) THEN 
        V_SQL_WHERE := V_SQL_WHERE || ' AND ';
      END IF;

      V_SQL_WHERE := V_SQL_WHERE || ' emp_name='||EMPNAME;
    END IF; 

    IF(V_empsalIS NOT NULL) THEN

      IF (V_SQL_WHERE is not null) THEN 
         V_SQL_WHERE := V_SQL_WHERE || ' AND ';
      END IF; 
      V_SQL_WHERE := V_SQL_WHERE || ' emp_sal=' || empsal;
      V_SQL_WHERE := V_SQL_WHERE || ' AND ACTIVE =''Y''' ;

    END IF; 

    IF (V_SQL_WHERE is not null) then
      V_SQL := V_SQL || ' WHERE ' || V_SQL_WHERE;
    end if;

        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_SQL;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      V_check:= '' ;
    END;
```

Comment: Just an info,this is having small issue.you need to add single quotes between each whaere clause input parameter

Answer (score 0):

You can create one from scratch, including if's and elses, or you can use a package called plsql-utils, the SQL_BUILDER_PKG.  It does the whole work for you.

Have a look on **SQL utilities**

http://code.google.com/p/plsql-utils/

Eg:

```
declare
  l_my_query sql_builder_pkg.t_query;
  l_sql varchar2(32000);
begin

  sql_builder_pkg.add_select (l_my_query, 'ename');
  sql_builder_pkg.add_select (l_my_query, 'sal');
  sql_builder_pkg.add_select (l_my_query, 'deptno');
  sql_builder_pkg.add_from (l_my_query, 'emp');
  sql_builder_pkg.add_where (l_my_query, 'ename = :p_ename');
  sql_builder_pkg.add_where (l_my_query, 'sal > :p_sal');
  l_sql := sql_builder_pkg.get_sql (l_my_query);
  dbms_output.put_line (l_sql);
end;
```

I used it in one project and it was a good tool.

Comment: how to do with simple if statements

Comment: I guess realspirituals already answered this one below.  It's not perfect, but you can have the desired result.  If you are going to create more dynamic queries, I still suggest you to use the package above.

Comment: I am trying to do like this: V_SQL := V_SQL || 'emp_id='||empid||; But it is giving errrors

Comment: my procedure not exposed to public ,this is internal to server. SO how to fix that?package you mentioned ,is it come by default?How to check whether package exist or not?

Comment: You should have permissions to create/run packages.  Next install the package downloading the file, unziping it and installing only the files sql_builder_pkg.pkb and sql_builder_pkg.pks.  Try running the example above and it should return the query.

Comment: i think,that is not very easy to install the package,we need lot of approvals.Can you tell me how to fix this: V_SQL := V_SQL || 'emp_id='||empid||;

Comment: Sure: just remove the last double pipes V_SQL := V_SQL || 'emp_id='||empid;

Comment: thanks, V_SQL := V_SQL ||' AND ACTIVE ='Y';.How to escape characters between'Y'.

Comment: you write twice single quotes V_SQL := V_SQL ||' AND ACTIVE =''Y''';

Comment: did you try V_SQL := V_SQL ||' AND ACTIVE =''Y''';  ?  there are 2 single quotes between Y and one single quote to close the statement.

Comment: i understand the problem,how to append single quote between each input parameter value ,suppose take empname as "jhon".V_SQL := V_SQL || ' AND emp_name='||EMPNAME;this should become 
V_SQL := V_SQL || ' AND emp_name='jhon';
 at run time?

Comment: @raj check my comment in my answer... you should be able to do that

Answer (score 0):

Something like this: (Not tested, but just an idea)

```
BEGIN
    IF EMPID IS NOT NULL
    THEN
        CLAUSE1   := 'EMP_ID = EMPID';
    ELSE
        CLAUSE1   := '1=1';
    END IF;

    IF EMPNAME IS NOT NULL
    THEN
        CLAUSE2   := 'EMP_NAME = EMPNAME';
    ELSE
        CLAUSE2   := '1=1';
    END IF;

    IF EMPSAL IS NOT NULL
    THEN
        CLAUSE3   := 'EMP_SAL = EMPSAL';
    ELSE
        CLAUSE3   := '1=1';
    END IF;

    IF (    EMPSAL IS NULL
        AND EMPNAME IS NULL
        AND EMPID IS NOT NULL )
    THEN
        CLAUSE1   := '1=0';
        CLAUSE2   := '1=0';

        CLAUSE3   := '1=0';
    END IF;

    QUERY_STR   :=
           '    SELECT EMP_NAME INTO V_EMP_NAME FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE'
        || CLAUSE1
        || ' AND '
        || CLAUSE2
        || ' AND '
        || CLAUSE3;
END;
```

Comment: you are missing quotes. EMP_SAL='<<value>>' .How to write value in single quotes

Comment: You want to hardcode!! THen try this `empsalvalues varchar2(100) := '1020';` and use the same in `'select * from table where column = (' || empsalvalues || ')'`

Comment: Better post schema details (with create table and inserts, and the required output, snippet you have tried so far), we can help.